# Google workspace add on for Google calendar throws 503 error on event meeting launch of authorization url

Tags: google-workspace-add-ons

I am building a Google Workspace add-on for Google Calendar. The add on is showing in my conference dropdown, but when I try to launch it so the user can go to the login page from my website to get the authorization, google is throwing a 503 error.
I added the proper permissions I believe in the manifest

```
"oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.addons.execute",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.addons.current.event.write",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.locale"
  ],
```

I contacted google and they told me to go to stackoverflow. Unbelievable.
I can provide whatever info you may need.
If someone came across this please help, I would much appreciate it
Regards

Comment: Please edit your title. It's not descriptive of your question. It's a generic title that can be applied to a lot of different questions.